# Save an element into a variable fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to save an element into a variable like this:

```
var callID = 3;
$active2 = $(".paging a[rel='callID']");
```

The class "paging" looks like this:

```
<div class="paging">
    <a href="#" rel="1">1</a>
    <a href="#" rel="2">2</a>
    <a href="#" rel="3">3</a>
</div>
```

But when I am consol.log($active2) there is only "[]" a empty bracket...so something has to be wrong about this part:

```
$active2 = $(".paging a[rel='callID']");
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

-Thanks

Kind Regards

Comment: @HarryJoy yea it's not required but i my opinion good practice to distinguish quickly between jquery objects and regular variables. Also it's not the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$active2 = $(".paging a[rel='" + callID + "']");
```

callID is the name of a variable, so in your examples you were literally looking for a anchor tag who had a `rel` attribute of `callID`.

Also, unrelated to your problem, don't forget to declare you `$active2` variable somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

callID is a variable. now you search for A with rel 'callID' not the value of `callID`

```
$active2 = $(".paging a[rel='"+callID+"']");
```